# Parse string to specific type of int (int8, int16, int32, int64)

Tags: go

I am trying to parse a string into an integer in Go. The Problem I found with it is in the documentation its mentioned syntax is as follows:

```
ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int)
```

where, `s` is the string to be parsed, `base` is implied by the string's prefix: base 16 for "0x", base 8 for "0", and base 10 otherwise.

The `bitSize` parameter is where I am facing problem. As per documentation of [ParseInt](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt), it specifies the integer type that the result must fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8, int16, int32, and int64.

But for all the values like 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64. I am getting same type return value. I.e of int64 type.

Could anyone point me out what am I missing.

Code:  https://play.golang.org/p/F3LbUh_maY

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)

> func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)

ParseInt always return `int64` no matter what. Moreover

> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must
>   fit into

So basically the your `bitSize` parameter only tells that the string value that you are going to parse should fit the bitSize after parsing. If not, out of range will happen.

Like in this <kbd>[PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/4St_EVhgNq)</kbd>:  `strconv.ParseInt("192", 10, 8)` (as you see the value after the parsing would be bigger than maximum value of `int8`).

If you want to parse it to whatever value you need, just use `int8(i)` afterwards (`int8`, `int16`, `int32`).

**P.S.** because you touched the topic how to convert to specific intX, I would outline that it is also possible to convert to [unsigned int](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint).

Answer (score 47):

`ParseInt` always returns an `int64`, and you need to convert the result to your desired type. When you pass `32` as the third argument, then you'll get a parse error if the parsed value won't fit into an `int32`, but the returned type is always `int64`.

For example:

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt("9207", 10, 32)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
result := int32(i)
fmt.Printf("Parsed int is %d\n", result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sscan`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   {
      var n int8
      fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
      fmt.Println(n == 100)
   }
   {
      var n int16
      fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
      fmt.Println(n == 100)
   }
   {
      var n int32
      fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
      fmt.Println(n == 100)
   }
   {
      var n int64
      fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
      fmt.Println(n == 100)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sscan